# Reactive extensions: matching complex key press sequence

Tags: c#, system.reactive, keypress

What I'm trying to achieve is to handle some complex key press and release sequence with Rx. I have some little experience with Rx, but it's clearly not enough for my current undertaking, so I'm here for some help.

My WinForms app is running in the background, only visible in a system tray. By a given key sequence I want to activate one of it's forms. Btw, to hook up to the global key presses I'm using a nice library http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/ I'm able to receive every key down and key up events, and while key is down multiple KeyDown events are produced (with a standard keyboard repeat rate).

One of example key sequence I want to capture is a quick double Ctrl + Insert key presses (like holding Ctrl key and pressing Insert twice in a given period of time). Here is what I have currently in my code:

```
var keyDownSeq = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(m_KeyboardHookManager, "KeyDown");
var keyUpSeq = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(m_KeyboardHookManager, "KeyUp");

var ctrlDown = keyDownSeq.Where(ev => ev.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey).Select(_ => true);
var ctrlUp = keyUpSeq.Where(ev => ev.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey).Select(_ => false);
```

But then I'm stuck. My idea is that I need somehow to keep track of if the Ctrl key is down. One way is to create some global variable for that, and update it in some Merge listener

```
Observable.Merge(ctrlDown, ctrlUp)                
    .Do(b => globabl_bool = b)
    .Subscribe();
```

But I think it ruins the whole Rx approach. Any ideas on how to achieve that while staying in Rx paradigm?

Then while the Ctrl is down I need to capture two Insert presses within a given time. I was thinking about using the Buffer:

```
var insertUp = keyUpSeq.Where(ev => ev.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.Insert);
insertUp.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 2)
    .Do((buffer) => { if (buffer.Count == 2) Debug.WriteLine("happened"); })
    .Subscribe();
```

However I'm not sure if it's most efficient way, because Buffer will produce events every one second, even if there was no any key pressed. Is there a better way? And I also need to combine that with Ctrl down somehow.

So once again, I need to keep track of double Insert press while Ctrl is down. Am I going in the right direction?

P.S. another possible approach is to subscribe to Insert observable only while Ctrl is down. Not sure how to achieve that though. Maybe some ideas on this as well?

**EDIT:** Another problem I've found is that Buffer doesn't suit my needs exactly. The problem comes from the fact that Buffer produces samples every two seconds, and if my first press belongs to the first buffer, and second to the next one, then nothing happens. How to overcome that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, welcome to the brain-bending magic of the Reactive Framework! :)

Try this out, it should get you started on what you're after - comments in line to describe whats going on:

```
using(var hook = new KeyboardHookListener(new GlobalHooker()))
{
    hook.Enabled = true;
    var keyDownSeq = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(hook, "KeyDown");
    var keyUpSeq = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(hook, "KeyUp");    

    var ctrlPlus =
        // Start with a key press...
        from keyDown in keyDownSeq

        // and that key is the lctrl key...
        where keyDown.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey

        from otherKeyDown in keyDownSeq
            // sample until we get a keyup of lctrl...
            .TakeUntil(keyUpSeq
                .Where(e => e.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey))

            // but ignore the fact we're pressing lctrl down
            .Where(e => e.EventArgs.KeyCode != Keys.LControlKey)
        select otherKeyDown;

    using(var sub = ctrlPlus
           .Subscribe(e => Console.WriteLine("CTRL+" + e.EventArgs.KeyCode)))
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now this doesn't do exactly what you specified, but with a little tweaking, it could be easily adapted. The key bit is the implicit `SelectMany` calls in the sequential `from` clauses of the combined linq query - as a result, a query like:

```
var alphamabits = 
    from keyA in keyDown.Where(e => e.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    from keyB in keyDown.Where(e => e.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.B)
    from keyC in keyDown.Where(e => e.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    from keyD in keyDown.Where(e => e.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.D)
    from keyE in keyDown.Where(e => e.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.E)
    from keyF in keyDown.Where(e => e.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.F)
    select new {keyA,keyB,keyC,keyD,keyE,keyF};
```

translates (very) roughly into:

```
if A, then B, then C, then..., then F -> return one {a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

Make sense?

(ok, since you've read this far...)

```
var ctrlinsins =
    from keyDown in keyDownSeq
    where keyDown.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey
    from firstIns in keyDownSeq
      // optional; abort sequence if you leggo of left ctrl
      .TakeUntil(keyUpSeq.Where(e => e.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey))
      .Where(e => e.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.Insert)
    from secondIns in keyDownSeq
      // optional; abort sequence if you leggo of left ctrl
      .TakeUntil(keyUpSeq.Where(e => e.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey))
      .Where(e => e.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.Insert)
    select "Dude, it happened!";
```

Comment: Okay, it took some time for me to get back to this question and check how your example works. Indeed it is! It's really a totally different approach than I had, so it's very interesting to read. I've made some modifications though, regarding the timeout between 2 insert presses, but it's really small. I need to grasp into SelectMany stuff, it seems very interesting but complex.

Comment: I tried that package and neither of your two examples work with a Systray Application.
A global hook normally works globally.
Tested on Net 7.0
In general there seems to be no one using that package, I found only 2-3 mentions online (and those also didn't trigger)

Answer (score 1):

All right, I've come up with some solution. It works, but has some limits which I'll explain further. I'll not accept the answer for some time, maybe somebody else will offer a better and more generic way to solve this problem. Anyway, here's the current solution:

```
private IDisposable SetupKeySequenceListener(Keys modifierKey, Keys doubleClickKey, TimeSpan doubleClickDelay, Action<Unit> actionHandler)
{
    var keyDownSeq = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(m_KeyboardHookManager, "KeyDown");
    var keyUpSeq = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(m_KeyboardHookManager, "KeyUp");

    var modifierIsPressed = Observable
        .Merge(keyDownSeq.Where(ev => (ev.EventArgs.KeyCode | modifierKey) == modifierKey).Select(_ => true),
               keyUpSeq.Where(ev => (ev.EventArgs.KeyCode | modifierKey) == modifierKey).Select(_ => false))
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Do(b => Debug.WriteLine("Ctrl is pressed: " + b.ToString()));

    var mainKeyDoublePressed = Observable
        .TimeInterval(keyDownSeq.Where(ev => (ev.EventArgs.KeyCode | doubleClickKey) == doubleClickKey))
        .Select((val) => val.Interval)
        .Scan((ti1, ti2) => ti2)
        .Do(ti => Debug.WriteLine(ti.ToString()))
        .Select(ti => ti < doubleClickDelay)
        .Merge(keyUpSeq.Where(ev => (ev.EventArgs.KeyCode | doubleClickKey) == doubleClickKey).Select(_ => false))
        .Do(b => Debug.WriteLine("Insert double pressed: " + b.ToString()));

    return Observable.CombineLatest(modifierIsPressed, mainKeyDoublePressed)
        .ObserveOn(WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current)
        .Where((list) => list.All(elem => elem))
        .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
        .Do(actionHandler)
        .Subscribe();
}
```

Usage:

```
var subscriptionHandler = SetupKeySequenceListener(
    Keys.LControlKey | Keys.RControlKey, 
    Keys.Insert | Keys.C, 
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5),
    _ => { WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; Show(); Debug.WriteLine("IT HAPPENED"); });
```

Let me explain what's going on here, maybe it will be useful for some. I'm essentially setting up 3 Observables, one is for modifier key (`modifierIsPressed`), another for key which needs to be double-clicked when modifier is pressed to activate the sequence (`mainKeyDoublePressed`), and the last that combines the two first.

First one is pretty straightforward: just convert key presses and releases to bool (using the `Select`). `DistinctUntilChanged` is needed because of if user press and holds some key, multiple events are generated. What I'm getting in this observable is a sequence of booleans, saying if modifier key is down.

Then the most tricky one, where the main key is handled. Let's go step by step:

1. I'm using `TimeInterval` to replace *key down* (it's important) events with the timespans
2. Then I'm getting the *actual* timespans out with `Select` function (to prepare for the next step)
3. Then comes the most tricky thing, the `Scan`. What it does is takes each two consecutive elements from previous sequence (timespans in our case) and passes them into a function as two parameters. Output of that function (which has to be of the same type as the parameters, a timespan) is passed further. The function in my case does very simple thing: just returns the second parameter.

Why? It's time to remember my actual task here: to catch double press of some button which are close enough to each other in time (like in half of a second in my example). My input is a sequence of timespans which are saying how much time passed since the previous event has happened. That's why I need to wait for two events: first one will be usually long enough, because it will tell since when user pressed the key last time, which could be minutes or more. But if the user presses the key two times quickly, then the second timespan will be small, since it will tell the difference between these two last quick presses.

Sounds complicated, right? Then think about it in a simple way: `Scan` always combines **two latest events**. That's why it fits my needs in this case: I need to listen to **double**-click. If I'd need to wait for 3 consecutive presses, I'd be at a loss here. That's why I call this approach limited, and still wait if somebody will offer a better and more generic solution, to handle potentially any key combination.

Anyway, let's continue the explanation:

4.`Select(ti => ti < doubleClickDelay)`: here I just convert the sequence from timestamps to booleans, passing true for quick enough consecutive events, and false for not quick enough ones.

5.Here's another trick: I'm merging boolean sequence from step 4 to the new one, where I listen to the key up events. Remember that the original sequence one was built from key down events, right? So here I'm essentially taking the same approach as with observable number one: passing true for key down and false for key up.

Then it becomes super-easy to use `CombineLatest` function, which takes the last events from each sequence and pass them further, as a List, to the `Where` function, which checks if all of them are true. That's how I achieve my goal: now I know when main key was pressed twice while modifier key is held down. Merging in the main key up event ensures that I clear the state, so the next presses of modifier key will not trigger the sequence.

So here we go, that's pretty much it. I'll post this, but will not accept, as I said before. I hope somebody will chime in and enlighten me. :)

Thanks in advance!